# Validacion para que me traiga un conteo de 3 meses antes de la fecha SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo esta lista de creditos

```
Credito FechaPago   FechaQuePago    AplicaMejora
51245494    05/05/2022  05/05/2022  1
51245494    05/04/2022  05/04/2022  1
51245494    05/03/2022  05/03/2022  1
51245494    05/02/2022  05/02/2022  1
51245494    05/01/2022  05/01/2022  1
51245494    05/12/2021  05/12/2021  1
51245494    05/11/2021  05/11/2021  1
```

Que saco de una tabla con una consulta super sencilla

```
SELECT 
C.CREDITO
C.FECHAPAGO
C.FECHAQUEPAGO
C.APLICAMEJOR
FROM CREDITOS C
```

Lo que hace es evaluar si la fecha que pago, no se paso de 5 dias de la fecha pactada (fechaPago)
hasta ahi todo bien, sin embargo quiero hacer algun tipo de validacion, que me identifique si el cliente ha realizado esto durante 3 meses consecutivos, para ser mas exacto 3 meses desde la ultima fecha de pago y que me haga un conteo de esto

por ejmplo, el credito de la imagen ha hecho bien sus pagos por 3 meses desde la ultima fecha de pago que es el 05/05/2022, como ese mes pago bien y los 3 meses atras pago bien, quisiera este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar esto al credito se le hara una mejora de categoria, sin embargo quiero identificar de alguna forma que se le hizo esa mejora y volver a contar 3 meses a partir de esa fecha que se le hace mejora, que en este caso es 05/05/2022 (siempre y cuando AplicaMejora sea = 1 osea que pago bien y que tambien cuente esa fecha ya que no se paso de los 5 dias)

como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Dos datos importantes que te sugiero para mejorar tu pregunta 1) que versión de sql-server manejas 2) lo que hayas intentado hasta ahora para resolverlo.  Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, lo que buscas podría encuadrarse en lo que se llama "rolling sum", o una suma móvil, la idea es tener la suma de AplicaMejora de las últimas tres filas, si es igual a 3 estamos bien.

Comment: Yo lo que recomiendo es que dejes de estar haciendo preguntas del mismo problema dando solo una parte de la información. Si es demasiado complejo, te recomiendo contratar a alguien o buscar apoyo dentro de tu empresa.

Answer (score 1):

podrias ver si algo de este estilo te sirve, basicamente agreag a cada fila el valor de la suma de la presente y las ultimas tres presentadas, segun FechaPago.
peor como comentaron, parece parte de un problema mayor.

```
drop table if exists #creditos
create table #creditos (Credito numeric (8,0), FechaPago date ,  FechaQuePago date,   AplicaMejora tinyint);
insert into  #creditos (Credito , FechaPago  ,  FechaQuePago ,   AplicaMejora ) values
(51245494,    '05/04/2022',  '05/04/2022',  1),
(51245494,    '05/03/2022',  '05/03/2022',  1),
(51245494,    '05/02/2022',  '05/02/2022',  1),
(51245494,    '05/01/2022',  '05/01/2022',  1),
(51245494,    '05/12/2021',  '05/12/2021',  1),
(51245494,    '05/11/2021',  '05/11/2021',  1),
(51245496,    '05/11/2021',  '05/11/2021',  1);



SELECT Credito,fechaPago, AplicaMejora
    ,sum(AplicaMejora) OVER (partition by credito ORDER BY FechaPago ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING  and CURRENT ROW ) 
  ,IIF( sum(AplicaMejora) OVER (partition by credito ORDER BY FechaPago ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING  and CURRENT ROW ) = 4 , 'Aplica mejora', 'NO aplica mejora')
  FROM #creditos
order by credito, FechaPago desc
```